# Biology shouldn't be aliased to Life?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

We have a Biology tag which is aliased to "Life" 
However, I am not sure this is appropriate for all the biological experiments  done in space (the description of Life aka Biology is closest to Astrobiology).

Should we undo the Alias of Biology to Life and make it a standalone tag ? 
Life should however Alias to Astrobiology is'nt it ?

Comment: The [tag:life] tag has had broad usage since the beginning of the site--being used for both astrobiology and the lives of astronauts in space, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I generally think of [biology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) as the deliberate study of living things.  It's a scientific field.  [life](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) refers more to the incidental presence of living things, such as potential extra-terrestrial organisms, or the contamination from one world to another.

I don't think too strongly on the issue, and I could be convinced of a better distinction.

[life](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) should *not* be used when it means [astronaut-lifestyle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronaut-lifestyle).

Comment: Agree on the last sentence. I think in that case questions should simply be retagged.