# What might a campaign to improve tag definitions and wiki's look like?

Tags: discussion

**Question:** What might be a good way to incentivize and/or promote the generation of definitions and wikis for undocumented or under-documented tags in this site?

I'm trying to think of perhaps some kind of campaign, or contest that would be both fun and helpful to the site.

There's no lack of users who are qualified, or of people who are naturally motivated to explain or define in helpful ways, but editing/improving tags hasn't been gamified ([1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27167/284619), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)) the same way questions, answers, or even to some extent comments have been. There are badges, but not the near-instant gratification of the up-vote.

I'm wondering if some kind of community wiki for proposed definitions and wikis of say the top 20 or 50 popular yet undocumented tags might work, but that's just one idea, there may be better ways, perhaps a special tag-hat or even [hat size](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/932/12102) mod?

---

---

What got me started writing this is the use of the [j-2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-2) tag on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30568/12102) about $J_2$. While I'm guessing the tag was originally created to refer to the [Rocketdyne J-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_J-2) engine, the OP likely started typing J or J2 in the tag selection box and it appeared like this:

> [image: the j-2 tag in Space Exploration SE]

and since there is no guidance either way is immediately provided, the tag was selected.

**edit:** The only tag currently on the question [Could a gyrojet fire arm be used in space or has it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30769/12102) is [space-gun](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-gun) and the problem here is that all the other questions are about a type of launch technology, not a firearm.

**update:** I've added a definition for this tag.

This reminded me of my earlier *[mea culpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mea_culpa)* meta question [Easiest way to get a list of tags for which I've bee the first user? Algorithmically if possible!](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/881/12102)

A summary of current results for @uhoh with 10 or more questions (there are 103 more with between 9 and 2 questions!):

```
uhoh-generated tags with 10 or more questions

definition and wiki          definition but no wiki
-------------------          ----------------------
identify-this-object         space-art
jpl-horizons                 flight-control
osiris-rex                   thrust-vectoring
parker-solar-probe           satellite-constellation
                             halo-orbit
                             exomars
                             sub-cooled
                             tess

neither definition nor wiki 
------------------------------------------------------
two-line-elements            turbopump
adcs                         frames
python                       lunar-orbit
skyfield                     iridium
near-earth-asteroid          visibility-of-spacecraft
entry-descent-landing        telemetry
grid-fins                    solar-eclipse
electric-propulsion          doppler-ranging
reduced-gravity-sports       reconnaissance-satellite
sgp4
```

Comment: I think one of the reasons that tag definitions/wikis are not very gamified is to discourage copy/paste or otherwise sloppy definitions/wikis. As tag definitions/wikis have less visibility than questions and answers and no direct means to flag for attention, problem behavior on tag definitions/wikis is a more challenging issue to tackle.

Comment: @called2voyage one thought I had which addresses that was some kind of community wiki, say every few weeks the top ten most used undocumented tags are listed in a wiki, and people take their best shot, then somehow several people have to agree before a single user takes the initiative (providing accountability) to transcribe the well-received definitions onto the tag. It sounds cumbersome, which is why instead of doing it, I've asked here to see if someone has a better idea. I'd be happy to do or help with housekeeping/implementation if we try that, since I'm the source of so many of them.

Comment: Maybe if we have two people sign-up for each tag: one to edit and one to audit. That way we almost have a guarantee that the information will be checked.

Answer (score 1):

For now, let's focus on creating descriptions/excerpts rather than tag wikis.

Here are the top twenty tags (by number of questions tagged) that have no excerpt (at query time):

just fyi this is what 224 characters or 32 words looks like when editing, and in final form as seen by users:

[image]

[image]

1. Tag: [launch-vehicle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/launch-vehicle)

   Editor: @called2voyage (done)

   Auditor:@uhoh (done)

---

2. Tag: [thrust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thrust)

   Editor: @uhoh (done)

   Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

3. Tag: [two-line-elements](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-line-elements)

   Editor: @uhoh (done)

   Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

4. Tag: [simulation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)

   Editor: @called2voyage (done)

   Auditor: @uhoh (done)

---

5. Tag: [soyuz-launcher](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soyuz-launcher)

   Editor: @called2voyage (done)

   Auditor: @uhoh (done)

---

6. Tag: [antenna](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna)

   Editor: @uhoh (done)

   Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

7. Tag: [exhaust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhaust)

   Editor: @uhoh (done, modified/generalized existing definition)

   Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

8. Tag: [robotic-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotic-missions)

   Editor: @called2voyage (done)

   Auditor: @uhoh (done)

---

9. Tag: [thermal-control](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal-control)

   Editor:

   Auditor:

---

10. Tag: [james-webb-telescope](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-webb-telescope)

    Editor: @uhoh (done)

    Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

11. Tag: [scientific-data](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-data)

    Editor:

    Auditor:

---

12. Tag: [collision-avoidance](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-avoidance)

    Editor:

    Auditor:

---

13. Tag: [calculation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation)

    Editor: @uhoh (proposed, should on-topic-ness be stressed further? (see python))

    Auditor:

---

14. Tag: [payload-deployment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payload-deployment)

    Editor:

    Auditor:

---

15. Tag: [heat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat)

    Editor: @uhoh (done)

    Auditor: @called2voyage (done)

---

16. Tag: [adcs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adcs)

    Editor: @uhoh

    Auditor:

---

17. Tag: [python](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

    Editor: @uhoh (proposed, should on-topic-ness be stressed further? (See calculation))

    Auditor:

---

18. Tag: [rocket-equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket-equation)

    Editor: @uhoh proposed/exploratory (has both Wiki and excerpt)

    Auditor:

---

19. Tag: [ground-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-station)

    Editor:

    Auditor:

---

20. Tag: [planning](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning)

    Editor:

    Auditor:

---

21. Tag: [astrobiology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrobiology)

    Editor: @Undo

    Auditor:

---

**Editors**, please add your name here if you plan to edit the listed tag. **Auditors**, if you add your name to a tag without an editor, please do not edit the tag unless there is an existing description or wiki. Please do not sign up as an editor and auditor for the same tag. Multiple editors and auditors on a single tag are allowed, but tags will not be considered complete until there has been at least one editor and at least one auditor. At that time, the auditor may mark the tag as complete here, when they have finished auditing.

Comment: I've added #21 `astrobiology` following discussions of tag usage and definition under [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31244/12102) It may need to be refined for the purposes of this site.

Comment: discussion has now moved to meta: [Does the astro-biology tag apply to all life in space, ever?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1069/12102)

Comment: @Undo I don't think your edit for `astrobiology` is sufficient. See [Does the astro-biology tag apply to all life in space, ever?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1069/12102) and also [Biology shouldn't be aliased to Life?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/879/12102) and if can add something to the discussion there it would be great!

Comment: per Wikipedia `soyuz-launcher` is also used for that "...and for commercial launches marketed and operated by Starsem and Arianespace." You don't say its not, but it could be read that way. Perhaps just add "as well as commercial launches" somehow? I'm not very knowledgable in launchvehicleology or the industry in general, so I'm not confident to make any changes myself.