# What's the best tag for the gas mixture that humans and animals breathe inside spacecraft or spacesuits, or one that they don't?

Tags: discussion, tags

What's the best tag for the gas mixture that humans and animals breathe inside spacecraft, or one that they don't?

[atmosphere](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere)'s definition says it's the stuff around planets.

> Questions regarding an envelope of gasses surrounding a celestial body held in place by the body's gravity.

I just added [air](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air) to [How much nitrogen did Skylab and the Space Shuttle carry for atmosphere makeup?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41602/12102) but I'm not sure if it's the right way to go.

**note:** Now I'm also wondering about atmospheres in spacecraft that are not crewed and do not contain animals:

- [Are fans ever used in un-crewed spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41226/12102)
- [Are there any uncrewed spacecraft that maintain an atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45191/12102)

Comment: Shuttle nomenclature was "cabin atmosphere".

Comment: @OrganicMarble that sounds like an excellent tag to me

Comment: but that would preclude suit gasses @OrganicMarble. Perhaps the existing life-support tag would be sufficient

Comment: okay `cabin-and-suit-gas-mixture` ;-)

Comment: @JCRM good idea, added, thanks! Perhaps that can even be an answer here?

Comment: I'd probably suggest "air-supply" as a synonym for it.

Comment: @JCRM it's giving me flashbacks from the 1980's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:All_out_of_love_(Air_Supply_song_-_sample).ogg

Comment: "air-supply" would be more the tanks and plumbing storing the breathing gases and bringing them to the cabin.

Comment: tag:gasses exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Cabin Atmosphere"

[ENGINEERING CRITERIA FOR SPACECRAFT CABIN ATMOSPHERE SELECTION](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19670027991.pdf) (1967)

Comment: I like it, yep!

Comment: Done! [Did NASA ethylene scrubbers “blast out submicron particles” which attack viruses and bacteria?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50715/12102)

Comment: My second use of the tag asks about the air inside a spacesuit. I've added that to the title of my question here but I think the tag can be stretched to encompass this air as well. I'll add some usage guidance to the tag

Answer (score 1):

[atmosphere](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) has been used for this in the past, but it probably shouldn't be overloaded that way. Whatever we decide the tag should be, those other questions need to be retagged manually.

Comment: We may not be able to [incentivize and/or promote with a special tag-hat](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1051/12102) the work and therefore distribute it amongst several users, but at least it's extent is finite and well-defined.

Comment: I've adjusted the question to include atmospheres not meant for crew or animals as well

Comment: Just fyi I've just added the tag [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50715/12102) as mentioned under OM's answer.