# Ambigous tag, "modeling"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A low-power tag on the site is [modeling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling), with a mere [12 questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling).

I see at least four different usages:

1. 3D modeling
2. Model rockets
3. Orbital mechanics.
4. Modeling of other phases of space-flight, such as launch.

This does not seem like a very useful tag. If you are modeling something mathematically, it's better to just use the name of the thing you are trying to model rather than the generic name.

---

Suggested actions:

- Get rid of this tag.
- Create a new tag [3d-modeling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-modeling) for the relevant questions.
- Add the relevant problem, such as [orbital-mechanics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-mechanics) to mathematical modelling problems.
- Replace with  [model-rocketry](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-rocketry) where appropriate.

Comment: Since there's only 12 questions, the easiest course of action is probably merging [tag:modeling] into [tag:3d-modeling] and then retag the questions that don't belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the positive feedback on the answer and my comment, I've gone ahead and merged/synonymized [modeling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) into [3d-modeling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-modeling). Please take time when you get the chance to review the questions tagged and remove/retag any that do not fit [3d-modeling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-modeling).

Comment: I have done a round of tag removals and re-tagging.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed.

This seems like an un-useful tag currently used for different things on different questions.

A 3D modeling tag is a good idea if there are likely going to be more questions and I think there certainly might and would welcome good on-topic questions of that type. We often have questions from people doing other things who need Space SE relate facts (e.g. I'm writing a novel about a Lagrange point and need to know some facts...)

Retagging questions not related to 3D modeling using other existing tags when necessary/useful is the right course.

---

just fyi this [list of tags that need a little love](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1052/12102) still has some uncompleted items.